# AWS Textract can not recognize the table of the second page of PDF document

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, data-extraction, amazon-textract

I need to extract table information from a billing copy using AWS Textract. It gives me almost perfect results every time but for some PDF document, it does not give me the table results of the second page.

code examples used: [AWS Official Documentation](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/python/example_code/textract/textract_python_table_parser.py)
image(JPEG) of first page is [image: first]

image(JPEG) of second page is [image: second]

So, AWS gives me the first 20 entries output as CSV. But for the second page of the image the result of CSV is: [image: csv output of second page]

and most importantly, I found the same results in a similar type of PDFs which has 21 entries and one entry exists on the second page of PDF. I have already used PyPDF2 to merge pdf pages into one page but doesn't solve my problem. Is there any OpenCV tools do I need to use?
Please suggest to me any possible suggestions for these types of issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `amazon-textract-textractor` [package](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-textractor/tree/master/textractor) to simplify calling the Amazon Textract API. It supports the SYNC and ASYNC API.

For example, using the second page of your document as input you can use it that way:

```py
from textractor import Textractor
from textractor.data.constants import TextractFeatures
extractor = Textractor(profile_name="default")
document = extractor.analyze_document(
    file_source="./pxqKO.jpeg",
    features=[TextractFeatures.TABLES],
)
document.visualize()
```

[image]

We see that there are two tables detected. Now we can convert the first tables to pandas:

```py
document.tables[0].to_pandas()
```

[image]

Then with respect to the problem of merging the table from the first page and the second page. You can do that directly in pandas for example. Here I run inference on your two pages and then use pandas to merge the two tables:

```py
from textractor import Textractor
from textractor.data.constants import TextractFeatures
extractor = Textractor(profile_name="default")
document1 = extractor.analyze_document(
    file_source="./yXYjr.jpeg",
    features=[TextractFeatures.TABLES],
)
document2 = extractor.analyze_document(
    file_source="./pxqKO.jpeg",
    features=[TextractFeatures.TABLES],
)

table1 = document1.tables[0].to_pandas(use_columns=True)
table2 = document2.tables[0].to_pandas()
table2.columns = table1.columns
table_final =table1.append(table2)
table_final = table_final.reset_index(drop=True)
table_final
```

[image]

If you have more complex use-cases you can use this other process for handling multi-page tables: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/postprocessing-with-amazon-textract-multi-page-table-handling/